# Discrepancy of header and detail level

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services, rounding, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a wired question.

We are maintaining header and detail table to maintain the invoices. Please see the below example.

Let say customer is selling 3 items each at $1.00 and apply a discount if $1.00 in total. So we are distributing this discount across the detail table as well.

Header Table

```
SubTotal    Discount    GrandTotal
3.0000      1.0000      2.0000
```

Detail Table

```
Item    SubTotal    Discount    GrandTotal  
II1     1.0000      0.3333      0.6667  
II2     1.0000      0.3333      0.6667  
II3     1.0000      0.3333      0.6667
```

We are using 4 decimal places in the database. 
We need to create 2 reports, one for each table. If we put this in to a report (ssrs) obviously we have to round these figures to 2 decimal places. Once rounded up to 2 decimal places the discount value of header report is 1.00 and detail report becomes (0.33+0.33+.033)0.99 in the report. There is a discrepancy of 0.01. Is there any workaround to eliminate this discrepancy?

Here are the reports.

Based on the header table

```
SubTotal    Discount    GrandTotal
    3.00        1.00        2.00
```

Based on the detail table

```
  Item  SubTotal    Discount    GrandTotal  
    II1     1.00        0.33        0.67    
    II2     1.00        0.33        0.67    
    II3     1.00        0.33        0.67
            3.00        0.99        2.01
```

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be rounding on the values you calculate with, just on the displayed information. A "displayed difference by rounding" should be perfectly fine as long as the calculation is correct.

Comment: in other words, round after the calculations - not before. :)

Comment: thank you guys.  but in reports I'm allowed to show only 2 decimal places which is 0.33 at each item(if i plot the detail table to a report). so if i sum up at the footer this becomes 0.99

Comment: @AsiriGunawardena change the **display format**, but not the **value** from where you calculate the summatory... aren't you able to do that? How are you calculating the sum or displaying the report? Is this c# or sql at all (as it's tagged?) if so, how are you using c# and/or sql?

Comment: What control are you using to display the data? Is this a web or a desktop application?

Comment: im using C# and sql server and this a web applications. Simply i want to create 2 reports let say in ssrs and display these two tables with 2 decimal places. when i display detail table on a report discount value becomes 0.33 at each item line. hence the total becomes 0.99. but the header report has a total of 1.00.

Comment: Again, the solution is: do not sum on the rounded values... sum on the full values, then display the rounded ones. Since you don't show any code whatsoever it's hard to tell where to put each.

Comment: if you sum on the full values the report it self will not tally. because each item line will show 0.33 and the final value will be 1.00. so there a discrepancy of .01 on the report it self.

Comment: @AsiriGunawardena which is perfectly fine if using rounded values for displaying is ok. If precision is that important for the report reading, then don't round intermediate values (or round them to more decimals). Check any official invoice with tax decimals, they don't usually sum up exactly, and that is perfectly fine